# In Jhipster I deleted filed through command and after run " gradlew liquibaseDiffChangelog " command but got this error

Tags: gradle, jhipster, liquibase

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'G:\Project\beequote\gradle\liquibase.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pathingLiquibaseJar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':liquibase'.
   > Could not find org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:.
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
og output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
```

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'G:\Project\beequote\gradle\liquibase.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':pathingLiquibaseJar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':liquibase'.
   > Could not find org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:.
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
og output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in JHipster and will be fixed in next version > 4.13.1, in the meantime you can fix it by adding version 3.6 in `gradle/liquibase.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    liquibase "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.6"
}
```